# How do I annimate between modules/views in MVVM?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, expression-blend

I have an MVVM Silverlight 4 application that holds a list of modules (a UserControl plus some metadata) in the main window's ViewModel.  I am displaying the UserControl of the module in a ContentControl (Content is bound to "CurrentModule.View").

I want to add a bit of pop to the app by annimating the transitions between views.  I've created Visual States for PreLoaded, Normal and Unloaded.  When the UserControl is instantiated, I set it's state to PreLoaded.  I have attached a GoToStateAction to the the Loaded event of the UserControl which sets the state to "Normal", performing a nice animation to bring the View in to view.  That works fine.

What I need to do now if animate it out of view when the user switches modules.  I have another GoToStateAction attached to the "Unloaded" event of the UserControl which sets the state to "Unloaded".  I know that current set up won't work.  The ContentControl can only show one UserControl at a time - as soon as the switch happens, the previous module goes away.  I can't say for certain if the animation is running on the view even though it's not visiable or not.

How do I accomplish what I'm after here?  Please keep in mind that Iam trying to do this in an MVVM-friendly manner, though I'm not opposed to *some* code-behind when it's purely presentation-focused.

Thanks in advance!  StackOverflow has never let me down!

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [TransitioningContentControl](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html?path=Layout|TransitioningContentControl).
It's a Silverlight Toolkit control that once you change the Content has a nice transition animation.

Comment: I think this will work.  It would be nice if there were more documentation on the available transitions.  There is also a Telerik transition control that I wasn't ware of.  It also works quite well with very little configuration.

Thanks.